# Oracle Apex - Derive pne column in IG based on another

Tags: oracle-apex

I have 2 columns in IG.

EMP_CODE and EMP_ACCOUNT

IG Query:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, EMP_CODE, EMP_ACCOUNT, DEPT FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS;
```

EMP_CODE is display only.

EMP_ACCOUNT is pop-up lov with list of values query currently as :

```
select emp_account from employee_accounts;
```

EMP_CODE is to be displayed from employee_codes table.

However the validation to be put here is:

Both employee_account and employee_code tables are joined by common emp_acc_id column.

```
select a.emp_account, b.emp_code from employee_accounts a , employee_codes b where a.emp_acc_id = b.emp_acc_id;
```

This is the relation between the 2 columns in 2 tables.

Now coming back to IG, EMP_CODE is display only and needs to be populated when EMP_ACCOUNT VALUE is selected.
So if EMP_ACCOUNT is 1002, then it's corresponding EMP_CODE shall be populated.

What changes would be needed in the columsn to populate EMP_CODE on basis of EMP_ACCOUNT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd **remove** `emp_code` from `employee_details` (drop that column); you know which code it is by joining `employee_details` to `employee_accounts` and further to `employee_codes`. Normalize!

Create a function which returns code:

```
create or replace function f_emp_code 
  (par_emp_account in employee_accounts.emp_account%type)
  return employee_codes.emp_code%type
as
  retval employee_codes.emp_code%type;
begin
  select c.emp_code
    into retval
    from employee_codes c join employee_accounts a on a.emp_acc_id = c.emp_acc_id
    where a.emp_account = par_emp_account;

  return retval;
end;
```

Interactive grid's query would then be

```
select d.emp_name, 
       f_emp_code (d.emp_account) emp_code,
       d.emp_account,
       d.dept
from employee_details d
```

Turn `emp_code` column's **Query only** property `ON`.

That's it, I guess.

---

**[EDIT]**

If you want to refresh `emp_code` as soon as you modify `emp_account`, create a **dynamic action** on `emp_account` which fires when it changes. Action should be "Execute server side code":

```
:emp_code := f_emp_code (:emp_account);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing solution! However there's one issue. The emp_code changes only after the grid is saved. is there a way to save it as soon as emp_account is selected from the select list?

Comment: Yes, with a dynamic action. See edited answer.